# How to get a numbered alphabetical bibliography with (author,year) citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm sure variations of this question have been asked dozens of times, but I couldnt find anything specific to my case.

I want a bibliogrpahy format which will accomplish these 4 goals:

1. get the citations in (Author,year) format
2. get a numbered bibliography
3. get the bibliography in alphabetical order.
4. use the natbib package, if possible

I have not seen any solution which can do these 3 things together.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you currently working with a specific bibliography style, and just wish to modify it so that numbers are printed next to the (alphabetically sorted) entries? Do you use a citation management package, e.g., `natbib`?

Comment: Yes, I currently use natbib & would love to keep it that way to avoid converting....

Comment: What is the purpose of the numbers exactly? Usually, these are labels for the entries but that is not the case here because you are using author-year labels. As described, the numbers seem a strategy to sow confusion in the mind of your reader... ;).

Comment: @cfr - Even if the numbers don't create confusion, they'll certainly contribute clutter. Either way, I'm also not convinced that it's a good idea to number the bib entries if an author-year type citation call-out system is in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution uses `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    style=authoryear,
    labelnumber,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{[#1]}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}  % from numeric.bbx
  {\list
    {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Smith:01,
  author = {Smith, John},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Article title},
  journal = {Journal title}, 
  volume = {13},
  pages = {1--2}
}

@book{Mueller:02,
  author = {M{\"u}ller, Hans},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Book title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address = {Address}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith:01}, \cite{Mueller:02} 

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Of course, if you're happy with the standard numeric style, there is an even simpler solution with `biblatex`, because one can make the difference between `citestyle` and `bibstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    citestyle=authoryear,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Smith:01,
  author = {Smith, John},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Article title},
  journal = {Journal title}, 
  volume = {13},
  pages = {1--2}
}

@book{Mueller:02,
  author = {M{\"u}ller, Hans},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Book title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address = {Address}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith:01}, \cite{Mueller:02} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I tried to implement it with my external NET.bib file, but i got an error that 'NET.bbl not created by bibtex'

Comment: @DankMasterDan You need to run `biber` rather than `bibtex` to create the `.bbl`. You should have a `.bcf` file produced after the first latex run.

Comment: Ok, so I converted to biblatex and it seemed that my .bib file was not being detected. Then I just made a new file & copied what was done above. And still I got an error output that non of the citations were defined (the output was "Smith:01 Mueller:02")

Comment: @DankMasterDan What id `biber` say?

Comment: @DankMasterDan: `biber` is not essential here. You may comment out `backend=biber` and use `bibtex` instead. If your bib-file was not found, have a look at `\addbibresource{references.bib}`.

Comment: @Timm: No, it should be `backend=bibtex8`, as `biber` is the default in recent versions of `biblatex`. It is perfectly possible to still use `bibtex`, but in that case highly preferrable to use the 8-bit version including the "Wolfgang" switch (`bibtex8 -W`) as the internal buffers of classical 7-bit `bibtex` are often too small.

Comment: yes! got it to work. Thanx!!!!