# How to number citations in the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I use lyx , elsevier class. I choose the citations to be natbib/numerical, style : plainnat. The citations in the produced pdf are not numbered. I am not sure how to number the citations. The lyx exported latex code is shown blow.

```
    %% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
    %% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
    \documentclass[10pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{esint}
    \doublespacing

    \makeatletter

     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
    %% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
    \providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=large}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    {\large{}\bibliographystyle{kluwer}
    \bibliography{citation}
    }{\large \par}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: With a minimal test case I get numbered citations, can you add the exported LaTeX code and/or the `.lyx` file to your question? (Remove all the content except for a citation or two first, so best make a copy.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I included the latex code exported by lyx.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have added `authoryear` to the class settings, which are found in Document --> Settings --> Document class. `elsarticle` loads `natbib` with the `numbers` option (for numerical citations), but `authoryear` overrides this. Removing that should fix the issue.

By the way, there are three bibliography styles specifically for Elsevier documents, so you would probably want to set `elsarticle-num` as the bibliography style.

Comment: So I removed the author year. it does the trick. But the problem is that in the text , instead of showing Ray(1997), it shows [15] for that citation. Can I have author year in the text , but also number the references in the bibliography section. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @YanSong Yes, you're clear, but you might have mentioned that (somewhat unusual) request before. It has been asked a few times before, but all the solutions I've seen use `biblatex`, e.g. [Bibliography style: name and year in text + alphabetically ordered and numbered list at the end](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175203)  [How to get a numbered alphabetical bibliography with (author,year) citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250665)

Comment: This is the first I ask this question. But I will check the list of questions you provided. Thanks

Comment: So I read a bit about this issue. I could not seem to find a solution. Can you explain how to do this in lyx.

Comment: @YanSong Sorry, it is not clear at all from your original question that that was what you wanted. Are you willing to switch to `biblatex`? There is some info on setting up LyX for `biblatex` in [How do I make my bibliography according to harvard-style (author-year, alphabetical by sourcetype...) in Lyx?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148410) If you manage to do that, then applying e.g. the solution from the second question above should be straightforward.